# Autolayout uitableview auto height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have following design.

[image]

Using AutoLayout but TableView only shows a portion of the items

`let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]`

[image]

I need all the items are displayed

Comment: you can set tableview height equal to contain size in constrain

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the tableview height according to your data count.Here 5 animals name ,so 5 * each cell height ,give to table view height then it works. In your view ,height of tableview not enough to show all details.

Answer (score 0):

Set Constraints properly so that TableView can calculate height properly, now set

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300 //Height you think you cell can have
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

if still need return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in tableView delegate HeightForRow.

Comment: @zetanova do you have nested tableview?